# Can't access OpenStack dashboard

Tags: configuration, openstack

I get an error on my OpenStack dashboard. I used the scripted method to install OpenStack through devstack.com. It had only two commands; I typed them down, and the rest of the installation finished by itself.

When the installation was completed, I typed my IP address on another system, typed the user ID and password, it opened, and in other words, it worked. Yet when I rebooted the system where I installed OpenStack, I started getting errors. My user ID and password were not allowed.

How can I fix this? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem with opening dashboard credentials means check for the `local.conf` file for some things like the below which i had in my `local.conf`:

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_TOKEN=a682f596-76f3-11e3-b3b2-e716f9080d50
```

and also check for environment variables which you will have to set for running all openstack commands

create one `admin-openrc` file and add the following things

```
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=password
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN=a682f596-76f3-11e3-b3b2-e716f9080d50
```